# how to set environment variable for parent process from child process?

Tags: c, linux

how to set environment variable for parent process from child process?

For example: 
I have PARENT and CHILD processes. CHILD process inherited from PARENT process environment variable called TMP_VARIABLE=777. How can I change the value of TMP_VARIABLE in the CHILD process to 999 that it's value becomes visible to PARENT process as TMP_VARIABLE=999?

Comment: I don't think you can. I don't think you can even change an environment variable in a child process from the parent process. Once a new process is forked, they are separate entities.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless the processes explicitly communicate (IPC, sockets etc.) and one explicitly tells the other to modify its own environment.