# why is my setenv implementation not permanently setting the environment variable

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, heap-memory

I have been tasked to write an implementation of the library function `setenv()`.

This is what I came up with:

create an array of strings on the heap with the number of words in the environment path with one more for the `new_path`, then add the path to the new temporary environment, the make the `extern char **environ` pointer point to the new temporary environment if the name doesn't exist, else point the return pointer of `_getenv()` to the `new_path`.

My implementation of `getenv()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * _getenv - gets an environment variable. (without using getenv).
 * @name: name of the environment variable to get.
 *
 * Return: a pointer to the environment variable.
 */
char *_getenv(const char *name)
{
    extern char **environ;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; environ[i]; i++)
    {
        if (!strncmp(environ[i], name, strlen(name)))
            return (environ[i]);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

And that of `setenv()`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "_getenv.c"

/**
 * double_count - counts the number of words at a pointer to strings.
 * @strings: an array of strings.
 *
 * Return: an array with:
 * a pointer to the number of words the pointer points to
 * an array of the number of letters in each word
 */
size_t **double_count(char **strings)
{
    size_t words, i, **array, letters;

    words = letters = 0;
    /* counting words in array */
    for (i = 0; strings[i]; i++)
        words++;

    /* storing word count in array */
    array = malloc(sizeof(size_t *) * 2);
    if (!array)
        return (NULL);

    array[0] = malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    if (!array[0])
        return (NULL);
    array[0] = &words;

    /* counting the number of letters in each word */
    array[1] = malloc(sizeof(size_t) * words);
    if (!array[1])
        return (NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
    {
        letters = strlen(strings[i]);
        array[1][i] = letters;
    }

    return (array);
}

/**
 * _setenv - changes or adds an environment variable (without using setenv).
 * @name: name of variable to be changed.
 * @value: value to change to.
 * @overwrite: flag to decide whether to overwrite name or not.
 *
 * Return: 0 on success, -1 on error.
 */
int _setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite)
{
    extern char **environ;
    char **temp_env, *variable, *n, *v, *new_path;
    size_t i, j, l1, l2, words, **count;

    l1 = strlen(name);
    l2 = strlen(value);
    v = strdup(value);
    n = strdup(name);
    variable = _getenv(name);

    /* checking for errors */
    if (!name || !l1 || strchr(name, '='))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (-1);
    }

    /* creating new string */
    new_path = malloc(sizeof(char) * (l1 + l2 + 2));
    if (!new_path)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < l1; i++)
    {
        new_path[i] = n[i];
    }
    new_path[i++] = '=';
    for (j = 0; j < l2; j++)
    {
        new_path[i++] = v[j];
    }
    new_path[i] = 0;

    /* copying strings to a new space */
    count = double_count(environ);
    words = **count;
    temp_env = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (words + 1));
    if (!temp_env)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
    {
        temp_env[i] = environ[i];
    }

    /* if variable doesn't exist */
    if (!variable)
    {
        temp_env[words] = new_path;
        printf("temp_env[%ld]: %s\n", i, temp_env[i]);
        environ = temp_env;
        variable = new_path;
        printf("_getenv(%s): %s\n", name, _getenv(name));
        return (0);
    }

    /* if variable does exist */
    else
    {
        /* if overwrite is nonzero, change value */
        if (overwrite)
        {
            variable = new_path;
            return (0);
        }
        else
            return (0);
    }

    return (-1);
}
```

Here is the test program:

```
/**
 * main - test _setenv.
 *
 * Return: 0.
 */
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int i;

    if (ac != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s name value overwrite\n", av[0]);
        return (1);
    }

    i = _setenv(av[1], av[2], atoi(av[3]));

    if (!i && atoi(av[3]))
    {
        printf("%s SET:\n%s\n", av[1], _getenv(av[1]));
    }

    if (!i && !atoi(av[3]))
    {
        printf("%s FOUND but not UPDATED:\n%s\n", av[1], _getenv(av[1]));
    }

    if (i == -1)
    {
        printf("%s NOT SET\n", av[1]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When I run the code I get output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu89 _setenv.c -o set ; ./set FOO BAR 1 ; ./getenv FOO
temp_env[49]: FOO=BAR
_getenv(FOO): FOO=BAR
FOO SET:
FOO=BAR
FOO variable not found
```

when I call `_getenv()` inside the function it shows that it points to the new `new_path`, but the function doesn't actually add the `new_path` to the environment, what am I missing guys?

and also when should I free the malloc'd array from `double_count`, should I do it for every successful return?

Comment: A child process cannot change the environment of its parent process. Even if your `set` command works, any changes it makes will be lost when it exits, and `getenv` will only see the environment inherited from the calling shell.

Comment: To really give your program an end-to-end test, you will want to do something like `system("echo $name")` from within it.  (Where of course you fill in `name` as the actual variable name.  Or you could cheat and just do `system("printenv")` and scan the output yourself.)

Comment: @SteveSummit using system("echo $FOO") prints BAR to terminal and system("printenv | grep FOO") gives FOO=BAR

Comment: @Marlon That proves your program is working just as well as it will ever be able to.  You are successfully setting the variable `FOO` in the environment of your process, and you are successfully propagating the modified environment to any child process(es).  But once your program exits, your modified environment is lost.  This is inevitable, an inherent property of Unix-like operating systems, as larsks was saying.  A child process cannot affect its parent in any way: can't alter the environment, can't change the working directory, or anything.  (All it can do is return an exit status.)

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543964.  (I'm sure there's a more canonical version of this question, with longer explanations and everything, but I couldn't find it.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Each string in the `environ` array has, and must have, format *name*=*value*.  For robustness, you can also support format *name*.  The *name* part may not contain `'='`.

   Your `_getenv()` only matches a *prefix* of *name*, since it does not verify the name is immediately followed by an end of string nul character (`\0`) or a `=` indicating that the value follows.  It also returns the pair, and not just the value.  You need to fix these.
2. Each process can only modify its own environment.

   For testing, you can have your `main()` do some `_getenv()` and `_setenv()` calls to verify they work –– I'd personally use command-line parameters for this –– and then just execute `/usr/bin/env`, which by default prints the environment, for example by `execl("/usr/bin/env", "env", NULL);`.

   The first parameter to [execl()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) is the path to the executable, the second parameter is the self-name the executable sees (`argv[0]`).  Any following parameters are command-line argument strings, followed by a single `NULL`.  If successful, the call will never return; the process is replaced by the `env` program.  It is common, however, to put something like `fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute /usr/bin/env: %s.\n", strerror(errno)); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` after the exec, so that if env cannot be executed, the user will see an error message instead of silence.

   If you want to use a shell command instead, you can do e.g. `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "command or commands to run in the shell", NULL);` instead.  To see only lowercase environment variables (because the standard ones are all in uppercase), you could use `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "env | grep -e '^[a-z]'", NULL);`.
3. `environ` is an array of pointers terminated by a NULL pointer.  Each pointer points to a separate string, either static/constant, or dynamically allocated.  (Unfortunately, we don't know which.)

   To add a new pointer to the array, you do not need to create copies of each string in the array, you only need to create a new array, copy the pointers over, and add the new (dynamically allocated string) pointer and a NULL pointer at the end of the array.  In other words, you only grow the array of pointers (and thus only need the existing number of entries).

   If you use `realloc()` to grow the `environ` array, you don't even need to copy the pointers over.  Just remember that `realloc()` may return either the same or a different pointer for the resized `environ` array.

   Because we don't know whether each pointer in the `environ` array is dynamically allocated or not, `unsetenv()` basically has to leak memory, and not call `free()` on the discarded environ pointer.

   [putenv()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) adds the specified string as-is to the `environ` array, removing any previous entry with the same name part.  In Linux (using GNU C library), if the string does not contain a `=` character, it is not added, but any previous entry with the same name part is removed.
4. In Linux, the [/proc/*PID*/environ](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) pseudo-file contains the initial environment a process was started with.  (It looks and acts like a file, but is really something that the kernel generates whenever it is accessed, not something that is stored in memory or in any storage.)

   It is quite possible, but not generally necessary, to keep this up to date whenever modified via `getenv()`/`setenv()`/`putenv()`/`unsetenv()`, and even avoid leaking memory (unless the user does so via `putenv()` themselves).

   This is done by using a contiguous dynamically allocated stack-like area (anonymous memory map with `MAP_STACK` and `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flags) as a char buffer, to keep all the strings specified in the `environ` array, with each string separated by a single `\0`.  When the area is moved or resized, `PR_SET_MM_ENV_START` and `PR_SET_MM_ENV_END` [prctl()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)s are used to tell the kernel where it is and how large it is.  (Those calls may fail if you try to use a normal malloc()'d memory region for it.)

   The kernel isn't at all interested in the `environ` array of pointers; that's just how environment variables are implemented in the standard C library.

   For process ID *PID*, you can run `cat /proc/PID/environ | tr '\0' '\n'` to see the initial contents of the environment area when that process started.  (This is also the reason we do not normally pass 'secrets' in environment variables or in command-line parameters (`/proc/PID/cmdline`), and use pipes or Unix domain sockets instead.)